# Set minimum pressure for it to count as a click in a wacom?

Tags: wacom, xsetwacom

I own a wacom tablet and the pen seems to be broken, it won't release the click. Money is tight right now so buying a new one isn't possible.

The pressure doesn't seem to be high (Highest I've seen is 3%), is there any way to make touches under a specific pressure to not register as a click? `xsetwacom`'s pressure curve isn't helping, as it still seems to register as a click.